# What would be the best approach to communicate between separate node processes?

Tags: node.js

My back-end app has two separate node processes. One for serving api requests, and another to process background tasks (eg. send email).

Answer (score 1):

I think that is what projects like Rabbit.JS is built for.  It's using the RabbitMQ messaging system which is pretty popular for these types of tasks.

http://www.squaremobius.net/rabbit.js/